# How to call specific rows and lines of a matrix and array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm developing a code where I have matriz 15x15 and an array 15 lines, but for a calculation, I only want to use the positions [3:12 15], so the matrix will be 11X11 and and array with 11 lines. How can I call just this positions?

```
kportico = np.matrix([[a1, 0, 0, -a1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, b1, c1, 0, -b1, c1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, c1, d1, 0, -c1, e1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [-a1, 0, 0, a1+a2, 0, 0, -a2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, -b1, -c1, 0, b1+b2, -c1+c2, 0, -b2, c2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, c1, e1, 0, -c1+c2, d1 +d2, 0, -c2, e2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, -a2, 0, 0, a2+a3, 0, 0, -a3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, -b2, -c2, 0, b2+b3, -c2+c3, 0, -b3, c3, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, c2, e2, 0, -c2+c3, d2+d3, 0, -c3, e3, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -a3, 0, 0, a4+a3, 0, 0, -a4, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , -b3, -c3, 0, b4+b3, -c4+c3, 0, -b4, c4],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c3, e3, 0, -c4+c3, d4+d3, 0, -c4, e4],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -a4, 0, 0, a4, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -b4, -c4, 0, b4, -c4],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c4, e4, 0, -c4, d4]])

f = np.matrix([[F1x],
               [F1y],
               [M1],
               [F2x],
               [F2y],
               [M2],
               [F3x],
               [F3y],
               [M3],
               [F4x],
               [F4y],
               [M4],
               [F5x],
               [F5y],
               [M5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create the test (smaller) arrays as:

```
n = 10    # Number of columns / rows
kportico = np.matrix(np.arange(1, 1 + n * n).reshape(n, n))
f = np.matrix(np.arange(201, 201 + n).reshape(n, 1))
```

To get indices of some range of rows (in my example *[3, 6)*) and the last
row (*9*), you can use *np.r*:

```
ind = np.r_[3:6, 9]
```

which yields:

```
array([3, 4, 5, 9])
```

Then, to get your slice of *kportico*, you can:

- select indicated rows,
- and from them select indicated columns.

The code to do it is:

```
kportico[ind][:,ind]
```

and its result is:

```
matrix([[ 34,  35,  36,  40],
        [ 44,  45,  46,  50],
        [ 54,  55,  56,  60],
        [ 94,  95,  96, 100]])
```

And to get the wanted elements from *f*, run:

```
f[ind]
```

which yields:

```
matrix([[204],
        [205],
        [206],
        [210]])
```

Note also that matrix indices start from **0** (not from *1*),
so your target slice shoud probably be:

```
ind = np.r_[2:12 14]
```

At least don't attempt to refer to column or row *15*, as it will
cause *IndexError* exception.

## Edit

What you should change in your answer:

In your code you omited the call to *np.r_*.
Probably you should change the fragment for *rotulado* to:

```
ind = np.r_[2:12, 14]
kportico[ind][ind]
f[ind]
```

Similar change for *encastrado*.

Comment: I tried your way, but I´m not getting the result that supose. For rotulado, the return should have 11 rows, and for encastrado 9 rows.

Comment: In my answer I wrote *ind = np.r_[2:12 14]*. This means that indices include: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 and 14. Total 11 positions.
Remember that *2:12* means actually *[2,12)* - without the right border.

Answer (score 1):

```
rotulado = 1
encastrado = 2

base = input("rotulado - 1 ou encastrado - 2?")

if base == rotulado:
    kportico[2:12, 14][2:12, 14]
    f[2:12]

if base == encastrado:
    kportico[3:11][3:11]
    f[3:11]



u = np.dot(kportico, f)
print(u)
```